# Search multi select dropdown angular 4 and material 2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Hi I am using angular 4 and material 2. I have a drop down with multi select options. I am able to display the dropdown with multi select option. Now I want to implement search/filter option in select dropdown. Could you please let me know, Is there any way to achieve this in material2 or I need to implement my own searchable component? Is there any thing like < mat-select-header >?

Answer (score 8):

Search textbox hasbeen added inside select box for filter

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select (openedChange)="openedChange($event)" placeholder="selectFormControl" [formControl]="selectFormControl" multiple>
        <mat-select-trigger>
            {{selectFormControl.value ? selectFormControl.value[0] : ''}}
            <span *ngIf="selectFormControl.value?.length > 1" class="additional-selection">
        (+{{selectFormControl.value.length - 1}} {{selectFormControl.value?.length === 2 ? 'other' : 'others'}})
      </span>
    </mat-select-trigger>
    <div class="select-container">
    <mat-optgroup >
  <mat-form-field style="width:100%;">
    <input #search autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" matInput [formControl]="searchTextboxControl">
    <button [disableRipple]="true" *ngIf="search.value" mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="clearSearch($event)">
    <mat-icon >close</mat-icon>
  </button>
         </mat-form-field>
    </mat-optgroup>
    <mat-optgroup *ngIf="(filteredOptions | async).length == 0">
      <div>No results found!</div>
    </mat-optgroup>
 <mat-option (optionSelectionChanges)="selectionChange($event)" *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
</div>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Go to below link to see implementation

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-searchable-multiselect-select

Comment: looks good - in the `selectFormControl.value?.length > 1` line what does the `?.` do?

Comment: turns out this solution doesn't work if your filter text includes spaces due to keyboard accessibility stuff in `mat-select`. I put `(keydown)="$event.stopPropagation()"` on the first `mat-optgroup` (around the search field) which fixed the issue

Comment: Wish I could give many upvotes to this solution!Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Try this:

```
<md2-select formControlName="some_id"  [multiple]="true">
<md2-select-header class="md2-select-header">
    <input #searchContact name="some_id" class="select-search"
           placeholder="Select Contact">
</md2-select-header>
<md2-option
    *ngFor="let contact of contacts | search:searchContact.value"
    [value]="contact.id">
    {{ user.address1 }}
</md2-option>
```

Comment: I am using <mat-select> , Does <md2-select-header>  work for it?

Comment: may be, not sure: https://www.npmjs.com/package/md2-select, you can do something like this

Answer (score 1):

There's an official npm package that aims to achieve this called [ngx-mat-select-search](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-select-search)

You can see the demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/github/bithost-gmbh/ngx-mat-select-search-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

From [issue 5697 of the Angular Material Github](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/5697), it looks like they want to add this into the official angular material repo, but for now we'll have to make due with this external package.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported at the moment. There is an open feature request for ["search/filter in select"](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5697) and another for ["Add select header to the md-select"](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2812). However, you can take a look at [this](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5697#issuecomment-364902502) comment which includes an example of how it can be solved if you don't want to wait.

Comment: yes I am about to implement this. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-search?file=app%2Fmat-select-search%2Fmat-select-search.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I would think creating an answer would be very simple, a matinput that has a search query and then using a basic search filter pipe on the array list of items that the list holds (I am at work, but when I get home I could possibly write up an example)